# Make a popup fragment on top of another

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I have a global activty, who manages two fragments (who replace each other alternatively).

I'd like to have a "popup" fragment in one of these two that would appear when clicking, either on a button, or on the screen itself (the implementations should not change).

So for now I have this :

```
final Button rank = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.rank);
rank.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
     FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     RankingFragment rf = new RankingFragment();
     ft.add(R.id.main_fragment_container,rf);
      }
});
```

So, ok, the fragment will appear on top of my first fragment.

But I want to, when clicking on this new fragment, it will disappear. How can I manage that ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You want a [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html). Here is a quick [tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html).

**Update:** another option might be a [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html), depending on what level of functionality you're looking for.